# Calling javascript function from within timer function in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to put together a few functions that call a rest API to obtain an ID and then use this ID to post to a different API and Im hitting major roadblocks. I've tried callbacks and promises but to no avail, the first function I use to request the ID doesnt execute before the second does so the $post fails. I've resorted to using setTimout which looks like it might solve the issue but for some reason I cant call a different function from within the timer function. Could someone please let me know where Im going wrong here thanks for the help in advance!

```
var timerVariable;

this.placeNewOrder = function(){
    this.newOrder();
    timerVariable = setTimeout(this.orderTimer, 1000);
};

this.newOrder = function(){
    //code to set currentOrderId
    return currentOrderId
    alert("got Id");
};

orderTimer = function(){
    this.postOrderItems();//this call never seams to call the function
};

this.postOrderItems = function(){
    alert("postOrderItems called");//, orderId: " + currentOrderId);
    //code to $post in here
};
```

Comment: I suspect `this` is not what you think it is when the method is invoked via the `setTimeout`. You can set the context of the function if you use `apply`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to keep the context inside `orderTimer` is to bind it:

```
timerVariable = setTimeout(this.orderTimer.bind(this), 1000);
```

Which solves the immediate problem you are having, but is a wrong way to solve your original problem.

Comment: Amazing thank you! I missed the "this." in the orderTimer function above also but spotted that at the same time, it works a treat now thank you!